# How to fix blank screen if application is swithed in RDP

Tags: visual-foxpro, rdp

Visual FoxPro 9 application wrotes to screen using ? commands

```
SYS(602 , 1 )
MODIFY WINDOW screen FONT 'Arial',14
_Screen.Themes = .F.
hide menu _msysmenu
ACTIVATE SCREEN
clear

do while .t.
clear
  ?'1 Option1'
  ?'2 Option 2'
  ?'.  Exit'

  wait 'Select ' to valik
clear
...
enddo
```

If running under RDP after switching to local desktop and back texts writter to screen disappears. Whole screen is blank.

How to fix this so that application screen output is visible after switching back to application ? I tried SYS(602 , 1 ) and SYS(602 , 0 ) but this
does not fix blank screen.

Comment: Don't use this ancient technique. Use a form (or a menu) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because screen resolution changed when you connect by an RDP.
On resolution change VFP repaint the `_screen` and clean all text. (text on screen not stored anywhere)
If you wanna save output you can add some layer on `_screen`,
for example a `textbox` object.
Its content permanently stored in `object.value` and saved after repainting.

```
_screen.AddObject('out', 'textbox')
_screen.out.Visible= .T.
_screen.out.value = 'sometext'
```

Or you can use `set alternate` for handle the output.